# Monocular camera and 1D laser rangefinder calibration

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ros, camera-calibration, sensor-fusion

I have a laser giving out range data and a monocular camera attached on top of it which is used for detection and tracking. I have the intrinsic calibration parameters of the camera. I want to establish a correspondence between the camera data and laser data. Is there any known method to get the extrinsic calibration matrix?? The end goal is to use x,y of the detected object from the camera and z (or depth) of the detected object from the laser.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question is still open, in this repo you'll find some Matlab code to get the extrinsic between an 1D laser range finder (or altimeter) and a monocular camera:
https://github.com/RiccardoGiubilato/1d-lidar-cam-calib

required are pairs of images of a plane with a printout of a checkerboard and "1-D" associated ranges from the altimeter.